# add row before header excel js in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, excel, xlsx, exceljs

i'm exporting json to excel by using excel js. json is getting sucessfully exported to sheet .but now i want to add one row which describes details of **sheet above the header text**.

for more details please refer [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI5Ou.png)

code as follows

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Workbook } from 'exceljs';

@Injectable()
export class ExcelService {

  constructor( private datePipe :  DatePipe) { }

  public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    const title = 'Absent Report';
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
   
    console.log('worksheet',worksheet);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    //const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);

    let titleRow = worksheet.addRow(title);
    titleRow.font = { name: 'Comic Sans MS', family: 4, size: 16, underline: 'double', bold: true }
    worksheet.addRow([titleRow]);
 
    // let subTitleRow = worksheet.addRow(['Date : ' + this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'medium')])

  }

  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
      type: EXCEL_TYPE
    });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + this.datePipe.transform(new Date(),"ddMMyyyy hh:mm") + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with your code is, that you are using XLSX from the SheetJs library but you are importing the ExcelJs library. You need to correct your import from EcelJS to
`enter code here`"import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';".
Secondly, if you want to add information before the header you can use

```
const sheetInfo1 = [
      ['preheader', '' + 'Pre header information']
];
 
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(workbook, sheetInfo1, { origin: 'A1' });
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(workbook, tableheader, { origin: 'A2' });
```

Answer (score -1):

I have something like this in my code and works fine:

```
const header = [
      this.translate.instant('grid.column1'),
      this.translate.instant('grid.column2'),
      ...        
      ];
    
    // Add Column header Row
    const headerRow = worksheet.addRow(header);

    // Add Data and Conditional Formatting
    data.forEach(dataRow => {
      const row = worksheet.addRow(dataRow.dataInfo);
      ...
```

Comment: sure! i'll check ASAP :)

Comment: It's unclear what this does.  it's incomplete.  it doesn't look like it answers the question. downvoting